# github windows runner shell selecting does not work

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a problem regarding GitHub actions using Windows and shell. It seems to select bash as shell even if I select cmd or powershell.

My workflow file looks like this:

```
name: build 

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  BUILD_CONFIGURATION: Release

jobs:
  android:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        submodules: recursive

    - name: setup cache
      id: external-cache
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: |
          external/lib
          external/bin
        key: android-external-${{ hashFiles('external/source/**/*') }}
        restore-keys: android-external-${{ hashFiles('external/source/**/*') }}
        
    - name: ndk-r25b
      if: steps.external-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      uses: nttld/setup-ndk@v1
      id: setup-ndk
      with:
        ndk-version: r25c
        add-to-path: false

    - name: ndk-r13b
      if: steps.external-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      uses: nttld/setup-ndk@v1
      id: setup-ndk-r13b
      with:
        ndk-version: r13b
        add-to-path: false

    - name: build
      if: steps.external-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      shell: powershell # cmd # pwsh
      env:
        ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: ${{ steps.setup-ndk.outputs.ndk-path }}
        ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_R13B: ${{ steps.setup-ndk-r13b.outputs.ndk-path }}  
      run: cd external ; ..\make\make -s -j16 TARGET_OS=android TARGET_CONFIG=${{env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION}}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Run cd external ; ..\make\make -s -j16 TARGET_OS=android TARGET_CONFIG=Release
  cd external ; ..\make\make -s -j16 TARGET_OS=android TARGET_CONFIG=Release
  shell: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    SOLUTION_FILE_PATH: .
    BUILD_CONFIGURATION: Release
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\ndk\r25c\x64
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_R13B: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\ndk\r13b\x64
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: rem: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It tries to select bash as command line tool.
A make executable is added to the repository (make 4.3 to enable file and drive letter support for Windows).

It does not make any difference if I select a different shell (cmd or pwsh). I did some test by just calling "dir" instead of make and it worked. It must have something to do using make? Any idea what's wrong here?

NB: The problem seems to be make inside make. so it selects a different make tool when using `$(MAKE)` inside make. So I guess I need a way to remove other make tools from `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

The "[Building and testing PowerShell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-powershell)" documentation recommends `pwsh` as the correct syntax for a PowerShell session.

You can try and use it to invoke your commands from a PowerShell script!

```
- name: build
  if: steps.external-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  shell: pwsh
  env:
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: ${{ steps.setup-ndk.outputs.ndk-path }}
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_R13B: ${{ steps.setup-ndk-r13b.outputs.ndk-path }}
  run: |
    cd external
    ..\make\make.ps1 -s -j16 TARGET_OS=android TARGET_CONFIG=${{env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION}}
```

Or, if it still does not use PowerShell:

```yaml
- name: build
  if: steps.external-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  shell: pwsh
  env:
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: ${{ steps.setup-ndk.outputs.ndk-path }}
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_R13B: ${{ steps.setup-ndk-r13b.outputs.ndk-path }}  
  run: |
    cd external
    & 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE' -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '..\make\make.ps1' -s -j16 TARGET_OS=android TARGET_CONFIG=${{env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION}}"
```

With `make.ps1` (to add to your repository):

```
param (
    [string]$s,
    [int]$j16,
    [string]$TARGET_OS,
    [string]$TARGET_CONFIG
)

& '.\make.exe' -s -j$j16 "TARGET_OS=$TARGET_OS" "TARGET_CONFIG=$TARGET_CONFIG"
```

---

The [OP markaragnos0815](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5706966/markaragnos0815) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202774/github-windows-runner-shell-selecting-does-not-work/76203676?noredirect=1#comment134384735_76203676):

> I found the issue: It is a `make` call inside make using `$(MAKE)`.
> It looks like it calls a different preinstalled `make` provided by a different shell which is found inside `PATH`.

That would mean the issue originates from the nested `$(MAKE)` call inside your Makefile. When the `$(MAKE)` command is executed, it might be referring to a different `make` executable available in the `PATH` environment variable, which could be causing the issue you're experiencing.

One way to resolve this would be to modify the `PATH` environment variable in your workflow and `make.ps1` script to prioritize the desired `make` executable.

Update your workflow file to set the PATH environment variable to include the directory containing your make.exe at the beginning:

```yaml
- name: build
  if: steps.external-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  shell: pwsh
  env:
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: ${{ steps.setup-ndk.outputs.ndk-path }}
    ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_R13B: ${{ steps.setup-ndk-r13b.outputs.ndk-path }}
  run: |
    $env:PATH = "$(Resolve-Path .\make)$( [IO.Path]::PathSeparator )$env:PATH"
    cd external
    ..\make\make.ps1 -s -j16 TARGET_OS=android TARGET_CONFIG=${{env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION}}
```

And update the `make.ps1` script to set the `PATH` environment variable as well:

```
param (
    [string]$s,
    [int]$j16,
    [string]$TARGET_OS,
    [string]$TARGET_CONFIG
)

$makeDir = (Resolve-Path .\make.exe).DirectoryName
$env:PATH = "$makeDir$( [IO.Path]::PathSeparator )$env:PATH"
& 'make.exe' -s -j$j16 "TARGET_OS=$TARGET_OS" "TARGET_CONFIG=$TARGET_CONFIG"
```

The `-j X` option will be preserved since you are still using the `$(MAKE)` variable in your `Makefile`.

---

And:

> I do a OS check in make after overriding the `SHELL` variable which depends on host OS. it worked on my machine :-) but not on github runner.

That means, the Makefile can include:

```
ifeq ($(GITHUB_ACTIONS),true)
  ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    SHELL := cmd.exe
  else
    SHELL := /bin/sh
  endif
endif

# Your other Makefile rules and targets follow
```

GitHub sets the `GITHUB_ACTIONS` environment variable to "`true`" when running in the GitHub Actions environment.
You can use this variable in your Makefile to determine if it's running inside a GitHub Actions runner and set the SHELL variable accordingly.

This way, the `SHELL` variable will be set based on the host OS only when running inside a GitHub Actions runner.
If the Makefile is run outside the GitHub Actions environment, the `SHELL` variable will not be modified, and the default shell will be used.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion. But I guess I found the issue. It is a make call inside make using $(MAKE). it looks like it calls a different preinstalled make provided by a different shell which is found inside PATH.

Comment: @MarkaRagnos0815 OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as a possible remediation.

Comment: This won't help since $(MAKE) does include all additional parameters, especially -j X option. This will be lost.

Comment: @MarkaRagnos0815 OK, I have rewritten the last section to propose another approach.

Comment: Seems like make selects a shell which is no cmd. I override shell on Windows but seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
my fault. I do a os check in make after overriding the SHELL variable which depends on host os. it worked on my machine :-) but not on github runner